# Writing a Windows driver for Pro Micro

Tags: c, windows, arduino, usb, driver

First off I have very very little experience with how USB functions let alone writing a driver; essentially trying to make this project a learning experience.

My setup consists of the SparkFun Pro Micro board and a Windows machine. I have a potentiometer wired up to the Pro Micro and my end goal is to send the value of the potentiometer to the host machine and use the value to change things like system volume etc...

The Arduino library came with a [Serial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/serial) library and I can send things over USB using that. I currently have a working Arduino program that sends 1 byte every 1 second, and a C program on the windows machine that "connects" to the COM port and reads the byte coming through (this part I have working fine).

The issue is that when the Pro Micro is connected to the computer it appears on a randomly selected COM port and I don't think you can tell which COM ports hold which device (not sure about this bit).

My end goal is when the Pro Micro is connected to the PC the host program should automatically recognize the Pro Micro and start processing the data that is coming from it. Setting it up as a HID device and making it appear in Device Manager as my own custom device is something I'd be interested in doing, especially for the learning experience but I feel that it might overcomplicate things.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I should do/look into?

Comment: Can you poll all COM ports and find out which responds as Pro Micro? I am not familiar with the board, but boards usually have a protocol that allows to identify them.

Comment: @DYZ I thought about doing that but I guess it feels like "cheating" so to say. Is there any to identify it by its hardware ID's or something? Also the Pro Micro is essentially a ripoff Arduino board.

Comment: I don't think it's cheating. It's exactly how the OS locates all attached devices on start-up.

Comment: @DYZ Point taken, did not know that. Should I just loop through all available COM ports and send a dummy message and see which one responds (of course I will program the board to reply to the message)?

Comment: Nope, not a dummy message, but a message that triggers the board to respond with its own identity. You will have to read the board programmer's manual to find out what to send.

Comment: @DYZ Again point taken, I will look into that, thank you. Also on a side note, back to my original post, will implementing a USB interface for both the board and computer be overkill? I'm a little confused between COM and USB since the board is plugged into a USB port.

Comment: If you can use COM, use it; USB is just the "carrier".

Comment: fwiw, i can assign certain "chips" to different com ports. for example, while my arduinos show up in com4, my cp2102 boards show under com10. all i did was change the port in control panel's serial section...

Comment: @skyguy126 Three possibilities: 1) check if there is a way to trace back the COM port to the USB hardware (on linux you can, on windows I don't know) 2) make the arduino reply to a message and test on every port (better if it sends back an identity and version number) 3) bypass the com port and use it like a native USB device. Use something like the V-USB library (I used it on an attiny2313 to control the leds). You won't have a classic serial stream, but rather communicate through packages. It's, IMHO, the best solution but also the most difficult and requires you to change a lot of things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe use windows internal tools like the *COM port database* (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff546481.aspx) or *re-assign COM ports* using *windows registry*, see

- [How does windows map the virtual com port to a device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754128/how-does-windows-map-the-virtual-com-port-to-a-device)
- https://superuser.com/questions/851192/change-com-port-number-programmatically
- http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_132_Re-Assigning_COM_Port_Numbers_Using_Registry.pdf

if you want to know the backgrounds: the arduino implements the USB CDC ACM class (Communication Device Class - Abstract Control Model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_communications_device_class) and emulates a COM port. Windows recognizes this class and loads the apropriate driver which is `usbser.sys` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/hardware/dn707976%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when the driver is loaded the new (virtual) COM port is accessible

the best sources are [How does windows map the virtual com port to a device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754128/how-does-windows-map-the-virtual-com-port-to-a-device), https://superuser.com/questions/851192/change-com-port-number-programmatically and http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_132_Re-Assigning_COM_Port_Numbers_Using_Registry.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Also just for future reference, in what scenarios would you need to write a driver. What is the difference between  writing a program that communicates through COM and a driver?

Comment: you need a driver to enable exchange of information between hardware devices, this includes such 'low-level' devices like graphic cards, hard disks, north/south bridge,.... the reason why you do not have to write a driver is that a driver already exists (usbser.sys). this is possible because of standardization. so you have to write a own driver if your hardware is not standard compliant (i.e. does not use the standard USB protocol,...) or if for your hardware is completely new so that you have to implement a driver that makes your device standard compliant or makes it work at all...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using libusbp, a C library that can be used to find the name of a COM port, given the USB vendor ID and product ID.  There is even an example in the "examples" folder that does just that:

https://github.com/pololu/libusbp

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it!